# Create relationship for association table

Tags: postgresql

Normally when creating constraint between two tables i used to use following script:

```
ALTER TABLE userVendor
ADD CONSTRAINT myrelation
FOREIGN KEY (DataSource, userId) 
REFERENCES user(DataSource, userId)
```

so `userVendor` table references `user` table

Now let's say `userVendor` becomes association table between two tables. Therefore we have additionally third table called `Vendor` which has datasource and vendor id as composite key. All of them by the way having composite keys.

**How to modify my script to say like (wrong script so far):**

```
ALTER TABLE userVendor
ADD CONSTRAINT myrelation
FOREIGN KEY (DataSource, userId, vendorid) 
REFERENCES user(DataSource, userId)
REFERENCES user(DataSource, vendorid)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to add two foreign key constraints, each referencing one table. It is no problem if a column appears in both constraints.

You will need two `ADD CONSTRAINT` clauses in your `ALTER TABLE` statement.